# the lambda(accounting) or factorial in prolog with tree

Tags: prolog

i have this test and my teacher is going to use one of these subjects in prolog and its tree.
but i have no idea how to implement them with prolog(since i dont even know the language).
i found something like this

This is just an example:

The following diagram shows a complete Prolog derivation tree for the goal ?-p(X).

[image: and the tree of goal]

as i said this is just an example of prolog's tree,what i need is how lambda or factorial is in prolog and its tree.

p.s: this is one of the homework's of terrence w pratt(programming languages design and implementation)

in prolog we have clauses,rules,goals and solution,for factorial how i can get these?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: as i said how we can implement lambda or factorial in prolog

Comment: Factorial is understood. But what do you understand by "lambda".

Comment: what i meant was the answer with either factorial or lambda would help me.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlch3 - this should help with factorial.

remember factorial is recursion so in java, it would be something like this:

```
public int factorial (int x){
 if (x != 0){
  return x* factorial(x-1);
 }
 else {
  return 1;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking in the wrong place for code for "factorial" or "lambda" in Prolog. Google is the place to look. It took me less than 5 minutes to find code on Google for factorial and lambda.
I tried to post the code here but it said "the code was not properly formatted - please indent all code by 4 spaces", so I gave up.